# How to return float value with zero fraction in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, zero, fractions

I am trying to retrieve float values from **MongoDB** with zero fraction. But it doesn't work as i expect it to.

i.e.  I inserted a doc:
db.collection.insert({ _id: 1, floatVal: 10.0 })

while retrieving it gives as:

```
{    
    "_id": 1,    
    "floatVal": 10    
}
```

Whereas i want result as:

```
{    
    "_id": 1,    
    "floatVal" : 10.0    
}
```

Comment: Try this : db.collection.insert({ _id: 1, floatVal: float(10.0) })

Comment: It is giving error : float is not defined

Comment: One quick solution is to typecast "floatVal" in your code as a float.

Comment: Why do you care about the fraction part if it's `0`? Also note that the by default, the mongo shell treats all numbers as floating-point values.

Comment: This is very strange. According to docs : By default, the mongo shell treats all numbers as floating-point values.
May be in the shell it is showing as a Int but in your code , it might return as a float. Please check the same in the code.

Comment: I am using Perl driver for retrieving data from MongoDB. But it doesn't preserve zero fraction. And i need that to identify datatype of the value which is stored in MongoDB.